# Is it possible to see deleted answers?

Tags: support, feature-request

I saw a thought-provoking answer to my question: [How many worlds are there during branching in the many worlds interpretation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/502211/)

Is there anyway for me to re-see the answer before it was deleted?

Comment: If not can I atleast know the username? So I can personally beg him for a discussion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer in this case was self-deleted by its author, for reasons which they are not required to articulate.  So the respectful thing to do is to let it be.  (Or, as JMac says, earn 10k reputation and come back to it.)

If that user notices this meta post they may decide to identify themselves.  But Stack Exchange intentionally makes it difficult to reach out to a specific user who hasn't posted or commented on a particular question or answer, because SE is not a social network. There are many meta discussions on that topic.

Answer (score 6):

I know one way, but it's likely not a very satisfying answer right now.

If you want to see the deleted answer, all you need to do is reach 10,000 reputation points!  At 10,000 reputation, you gain access to the [moderation tools privilege](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) which gives you access to some extra features on the site.

Included with that is the ability to see deleted questions and answers.

Comment: While looking at the answer to a particular question it looked much more greyish than normal. What might it be?